# Two navbars below the other one with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm starting with Bootstrap and have a small problem with the navbar-element. I need to declare a container with the width of 1024px and have to add two navbars. On at the top and the other one below it. Both navbars need a distance from the right div of 0px.

(Stackoverflow doesn't want to let me post pictures, but I think it's much more easier if you can see what I mean: http://www.abload.de/img/asdjraik.png)

As you can see the first navbar is working correctly, but now I need another one below it. Padding from the container under it should be exactly 5px.

My problem is, that the other navbar gains the same padding from the top as the first navbar. I can't get it below the other one. When I define the following classes for this problem another one comes up:

```
.small-margin {
    margin-top: 20px;
}    

.big-margin {
    margin-top: 110px;
}
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
    <div class="navbar small-margin">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="navbar big-margin">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">another link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">another link 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The second navbar appears on the left side of the first navbar and not below it. I tried a lot of CSS-fixes.

Anyone have a idea how to get the 2nd navbar below the first?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately didn't change anything :/

Comment: Have you tried adding .row and .span12 into each navbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your code and it's works

[image]

I also tried adding it into 1024px container

```
.container{
    max-width: 1024px;
}
```

this is the result
[image]

Your css code must be conflicted with the bootstrap. maybe you could try wrapping each navbar with `.row`. I believe that this solution is surely make all navbar separated.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    ... navbar 1 ...
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    ... navbar 2 ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting - I need both navbars in a container with max-width of 1024px. Didn't try it with full-width.